# Altair: Globe map centering

Tags: python, altair

I am learning to map by Altair, following examples here [Example Gallery - World Projections](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/world_projections.html).

How can I set center of Globe map at my desired latlong point?

Below is my failed code trying to center the map at around Latitude= 40 and Longitude=140:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

countries = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

alt.Chart(countries).mark_geoshape(
    fill='#666666',
    stroke='white'
).project(
    type= 'orthographic'
).properties(
    title='Orthographic'
).configure_projection(
    center= [140,40]
)
```

As you see the map is still centered around the Atlantic Ocean, probably at [Long, Lat] = [0, 0].

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the orthographic projection, it is the `rotate` property rather than the `center` property that determines how the projection is centered. The `rotate` property consists of rotation degrees around the three principal axes. For example, to construct the projection around long=140, lat=40, you can do this:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

countries = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

alt.Chart(countries).mark_geoshape(
    fill='#666666',
    stroke='white'
).project(
    type= 'orthographic',
    rotate=[-140, -40 ,0]
).properties(
    title='Orthographic'
)
```

[image]

You can explore some the available projections and their configurations dynamically at this site: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/projections/